# ¿Cómo usar localstorage en una app webview?

Tags: javascript, java, app, webview, local-storage

Voy a comenzar a crear un proyecto pero quiero saber si es posible usar **localstorage** en una webview y que esta siga recordando los datos incluso si el celular se apaga, ya que será un juego donde se guarda los niveles, pero no sé si es posible y por eso no he comenzado a programar, cabe decir que no sé nada de java y por eso es un webview de una página web programada en html css y js.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

El uso del `localStorage` en una app basada en webview actualizado/estandarizado es exactamente igual que en cualquier navegador, es decir la API no cambia.

Lo que seguramente necesites es darle permisos suficientes para usar este almacenamiento. Esto puede variar un poco dependiendo de la configuración vía framework o librerias.

Un aspecto a destacar es que el tiempo de vida de los datos es definido por el programador ya que el `localStorage` no tiene expiración como por ejemplo pasa en las cookies.

En límite de cantidad de datos que puedes almacenar por este método es 2.5MB, en el caso que necesites más espacio podrías usar [Web SQL Database](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) que es otra especificación de HTML5. [Aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm) un tutorial en inglés.

El usuario solo podría eliminar esta información si accede a ajustes/aplicaciones/tuApp y elimina los datos en `cache` y de aplicación.

Aquí te dejo un link sobre el almacenamiento en lado cliente:

https://www.html5rocks.com/es/features/storage introducción

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/ artículo en inglés

Suerte, espero que te sirva en tu búsqueda.